# contenteditable line return

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wysiwyg, contenteditable

I've been working on a content editor for some time now using contenteditable. I'm really pleased with progress and am getting close to finishing the project the editor is being used in.

Trident/Gecko/Chrome all deal with linebreaks in contenteditable in different ways. I need a cross-browser solution to this issue. In Chrome if I give an initial tag, such as `p`, the editor will create new lines as `p` tags, however this doesn't carry over in Firefox.

This behaviour tends to break when returning out of a bullet list, as instead of creating a new p tag, it reverts to using divs for new lines.

I've scoured the web to try find a solution, but have so far come up with nothing. I know it's certainly possible as other editors such as CKEditor give you the choice over line break behaviour.

Unfortunately, I have a specific set of requirements which don't allow me to use **any** external editor. This thing has to be bespoke.

So my question is, does anyone know how to control cross-browser line break behaviour in contenteditable? Use of jQuery is fine, however want to keep this thing as lean as possible. Would really appreciate all the help I could get on this - you'll get a visible credit when the project is complete!

Comment: I'd check the source of CKEditor and/or TinyMCE to see how they do it. I have some ideas but it's always going to be non-trivial.